# ORACLE APEX SEQUENCE 'SCAN.SEQ' exists but it shows that it doesn't exist when incremented or retrieved its current value

Tags: oracle, sequence

The list of sequences consists of the sequence 'SCAN.SEQ' (Screenshot)
[image]

But when I try to retrieve its next value, it says that the sequence doesn't exist[image]

Can anyone help and tell whats wrong here that it says the sequence doesn't exist even though it is in the list of sequences.

Comment: scan.seq will not work, it will consider it as an owner.object, try recreating with scan_seq as the name

Comment: you can try this: select "SCAN.SEQ".Nextval from dual;

Comment: @Renato Afonso Thanks !! It worked